# GMapsFX not displaying but running

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to link my GMapsFX API with Java but I get an error when trying to use GMapsFX. I am using NetBeans.
So basically, Everything seems to be running without  errors but the actual display is "hidden" and I don't know why.

fxmlfile:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="443.0" prefWidth="711.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.lynden.gmaps.directions.GmapController">
   <children>
      <GoogleMapView fx:id="mapView" layoutX="-311.0" layoutY="-244.0" prefWidth="490.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="fromTextField" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="222.0" promptText="From:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="10.0" />
      <TextField fx:id="toTextField" layoutX="10.0" layoutY="10.0" onAction="#toTextFieldAction" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="222.0" promptText="To:" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="50.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

controller:

```
package tn.esprit.carngo.presentation;

import com.lynden.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.MapComponentInitializedListener;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.javascript.object.*;
import com.lynden.gmapsfx.service.directions.*;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class GmapController implements Initializable, MapComponentInitializedListener, DirectionsServiceCallback {

    protected DirectionsService directionsService;
    protected DirectionsPane directionsPane;

    protected StringProperty from = new SimpleStringProperty();
    protected StringProperty to = new SimpleStringProperty();

    @FXML
    protected GoogleMapView mapView;

    @FXML
    protected TextField fromTextField;

    @FXML
    protected TextField toTextField;

    @FXML
    private void toTextFieldAction(ActionEvent event) {
        DirectionsRequest request = new DirectionsRequest(from.get(), to.get(), TravelModes.DRIVING);
        directionsService.getRoute(request, this, new DirectionsRenderer(true, mapView.getMap(), directionsPane));
    }

    @Override
    public void directionsReceived(DirectionsResult results, DirectionStatus status) {
    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        mapView.addMapInializedListener(this);
        to.bindBidirectional(toTextField.textProperty());
        from.bindBidirectional(fromTextField.textProperty());
    }

    @Override
    public void mapInitialized() {
        MapOptions options = new MapOptions();

        options.center(new LatLong(47.606189, -122.335842))
                .zoomControl(true)
                .zoom(12)
                .overviewMapControl(false)
                .mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.ROADMAP);
        GoogleMap map = mapView.createMap(options);
        directionsService = new DirectionsService();
        directionsPane = mapView.getDirec();
    }

}
```

the output :

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9Anw.png)

the displayed window :

[window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ng8WV.png)

Comment: It appears you are using an old version of GMapsFX. The latest version (at time of writing this comment) is 11.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GMapsFX](https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/GMapsFX) has some [sample projects](https://github.com/dlsc-software-consulting-gmbh/GMapsFX/tree/master-11/GMapsFX-Examples). I tried them, they did not work for me.

Setup:

- OS X Intel 13.2.1
- GMapsFX version 11.0.7
- GMapsFX example apps with their default config (uses JavaFX 17).
- OpenJDK 19.

Where the map is supposed to display, instead there is a message:

> The page can't load Google Maps correctly

with a link to a google site that discusses various reasons why this may be.

Among the reasons provided (e.g. invalid use of API keys), is [browser support](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/browsersupport).

The JavaFX WebView browser is not listed as supported. This is why I am guessing that the maps for GMapsFX do not display. I did not investigate further to confirm.

GMapsFX uses WebView. The last time I tried (a few months ago), WebView was not able to display Google Maps correctly. It used to be able to display Google Maps correctly a couple of years back. My guess is that Google made changes to Maps which makes it incompatible with WebView.