# The route between two points is not displayed GmapsFX

Tags: java, google-maps, javafx

I tried to implement routing between two markers in GMapsFX in my student application writed in Java/JavaFX. I don't get any error, I just get the message on the map:

```
This page can't load Google Maps correctly
```

and in the console:

```
INFO com.dlsc.gmapsfx.GoogleMapView - Alert: Hide directions called.
```

When instantiating a GoogleMapView I don't specify a key, I don't think it's required. Attach the code and the effect of the program below. Is anyone able to help?

```
public class Map implements MapComponentInitializedListener, DirectionsServiceCallback {

    protected GoogleMapView mapView;
    protected GoogleMap map;
    protected Marker marker;
    protected MarkerOptions markerOptions;
    protected DirectionsService directionsService;
    protected DirectionsRenderer directionsRenderer = null;
    protected DirectionsPane directionsPane;

    public Map() {
        mapView = new GoogleMapView();
        mapView.addMapInitializedListener(this);
        markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
    }

    @Override
    public void mapInitialized() {
        MapOptions mapOptions = new MapOptions();
      mapOptions.mapType(MapTypeIdEnum.ROADMAP).overviewMapControl(false).zoom(18).keyboardShortcuts(false);
        map = mapView.createMap(mapOptions);
        LatLong latLong = new LatLong(50.0650887, 19.9245536);
        map.setCenter(latLong);

        directionsService = new DirectionsService();
        directionsPane = mapView.getDirec();

        Marker marker1 = new Marker(markerOptions);
        Marker marker2 = new Marker(markerOptions);
        marker1.setPosition(new LatLong(50.0750887, 19.9345536));
        marker2.setPosition(new LatLong(50.0850887, 19.9445536));
        map.addMarker(marker1);

        DirectionsRequest directionsRequest = new DirectionsRequest(new LatLong(50.0750887, 19.9345536), new LatLong(50.0850887, 19.9445536), TravelModes.DRIVING, false);
        directionsRenderer = new DirectionsRenderer(true, mapView.getMap(), directionsPane);
        directionsService.getRoute(directionsRequest, this, directionsRenderer);
    }

    @Override
    public void directionsReceived(DirectionsResult results, DirectionStatus status) {
        System.out.println(results);
        System.out.println(status);
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is probably not going to work, as commented on [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76022664/how-to-route-between-several-markers-in-gmapsfx-javafx) and as answered in this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75633283/gmapsfx-not-displaying-but-running/75668448#75668448)

Comment: oh, i understand. If so, can you recommend any other library that I can use in JavaFX to display the map? Where will I be able to display markers and define a route between points?

Comment: I commented on [your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76022664/how-to-route-between-several-markers-in-gmapsfx-javafx).